PIC16F26K83 ADC reading and LCD interface
I'm very new to PIC programming and I need help figuring out why the LCD doesn't show the second row. The shematic and code comes from this repository; https://github.com/PeacocksFly/PIC18-Projects-Repository/blob/master/LCD_voltmeter.c. I just tried to port it from a PIC18F45K22 to PIC18F26K80.
The first row displays correctly the string "Voltage" but the second row stays blank while it should display the voltage with two digits e.g "3.2V".
Video of what it should look like (from PeacocksFly) : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RN32fqTV_jE
The circuit (simulated in Proteus) :

The source code :
#include <stdint.h>

#pragma config WDTEN=OFF
#define _XTAL_FREQ 8000000

#define RS LATBbits.LATB0
#define RW LATBbits.LATB1
#define EN LATBbits.LATB2   

void LCD_Command(uint8_t cmd);
void LCD_Data(uint8_t cmd);
void WriteToLCD(uint8_t* p, uint8_t pos);

void main(void)
 {
   uint16_t result;             // ADC result variable
   uint8_t text[16];            // Array for string to send to LCD
    
   // Pin config.
   TRISAbits.TRISA0 = 1;        // Set RA0 to input
   TRISC = 0x00;                // PORTC configured as an output
   TRISB = 0x00;                // PORTB configured as an output
    
   // ADC config.
   ADCON0bits.CHS  = 0b00000;   // AN0 channel selected
   ADCON0bits.ADON = 1;         // Turn ADC On
    
   ADCON1bits.VCFG = 0b00;      // Vref+ connected to Vdd
   ADCON1bits.CHSN = 0b000;     // Vref- connected to Vss
    
   ADCON2bits.ADFM = 1;         // Result right justified
   ADCON2bits.ACQT = 0b100;     // Acquisition time = 8 TAD
   ADCON2bits.ADCS = 0b011;     // TAD = 1.7 µs (FRC)
    
   ADCON0bits.GO = 1;           //ADC conversion starts
    
   EN = 0;
   
   // LCD Config.
   __delay_ms(100);
   LCD_Command(0x38);       // Function Set : 16×2, 8-bit mode
   __delay_ms(100);
   LCD_Command(0x0C);       // Display ON/OFF Control : display on, cursor off
   __delay_ms(5); 
    
   WriteToLCD((uint8_t*) "Voltage", 0x80);  // 0x80 : Go to the first cell of the upper row
   
   while (1) 
   {
      while (ADCON0bits.GO);                    // Wait for conversion to complete
      
      result = ((ADRESL | (uint16_t)ADRESH << 8) * 50) >> 12;
    
      uint8_t* p = text;
      *p++ = 0x30 | (uint8_t)(result / 10);     // One digit before comma
      *p++ = 0x2E;                              // ascii '.'
      *p++ = 0x30 | (uint8_t)(result % 10);     // One digit after comma
      *p++ = 0x20;                              // ascii whitespace
      *p = 0x56;                                // ascii 'V'
      
      WriteToLCD((uint8_t*) text, 0xC0);        // Display result on the second row

      ADCON0bits.GO = 1;                        // Start the next ADC conversion
   }
   return;
}

void WriteToLCD(uint8_t* p, uint8_t pos)
{
     LCD_Command(pos);
     __delay_ms(5);
     while(*p)
     {
           LCD_Data((uint8_t) *p++);
           __delay_ms(5);
     }
}

void LCD_Command(uint8_t cmd)
{
    LATC = cmd;
    RS = 0;
    RW = 0;
    EN = 1;
    __delay_ms(1);
    EN = 0;
}

void LCD_Data(uint8_t cmd)
{
    LATC = cmd;
    RS = 1;
    RW = 0;
    EN = 1;
    __delay_ms(1);
    EN = 0;
}


Usually the 2nd row missing with is because of bad initialization. Not all the HD44780-compatible chips are the same in timing.

I checked but what is wierd is that when for example, I write : "WriteToLCD((uint8_t*) "Hello", 0xC0);" after the "WriteToLCD((uint8_t*) "Voltage", 0x80);", but before the while(1) loop, the LCD correctly displays "Voltage" on the first row and "Hello" on the second row.

You need to add null termination to the data to be sent to the LCD so the write function knows where to stop.
When you use a character array, C puts that in there for you.

Two reasons why the line could be blank.
First of all, the code will halt indefinitely if the GO bit never drops.
If your code prints "Hello" and it never changes, the code is stuck waiting for GO bit to drop.
The next problem is, even if GO bit would drop, the voltage text string you build has no terminating null but it may write indefinitely until the 0x00 is hit at some point, but it would also print garbage to the whole display so evntually it would wrap from end of line 2 back to start of line 1, so depending on whem the 0x00 is hit, it may have writen the volt string but also any amount of garbage.
